# disable logging for specific lines of code

Tags: python, stdout, gensim

I am tuning the word2vec model hyper-parameters. Word2Vec has to many log in console that I cannot read Optuna or my custom log. Is there any trick to suppress logs generated by Word2Vec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code in python 3.7 in python 3.6 we have send `logging.ERROR` to disable function.

```
import logging

logging.disable()
#your code
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: If you were getting `DEBUG` level messages, there must have been earlier code that turned them on. It'd be better to fix that, than to completely disable logging (including `WARNING` & `SEVERE` level messages).

Comment: Thank you for comment. Unfortunately, In Genism many verbose logs are at ERROR level. However, they really log speed and stages of processing.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a logging-line? I've just searched through Gensim's `word2vec.py` source code, & the only ERROR-level logging is a definitive failure-to-load-a-model. Almost everything is at level INFO, while a few WARNING-level log events only fire once per training-run, & describe user errors that should be corrected. (If you're seeing many log lines even after setting the level to ERROR or higher, there may be other urgent issues to fix in your code!)

Comment: I just skipped it with the code I wrote. As you are familiar with the package here its starting lines:

2021-11-23 00:07:59,483 collecting all words and their counts
2021-11-23 00:07:59,483 PROGRESS: at sentence #0, processed 0 words, keeping 0 word types
2021-11-23 00:07:59,575 PROGRESS: at sentence #10000, processed 800000 words, keeping 10041 word types
2021-11-23 00:07:59,659 PROGRESS: at sentence #20000, processed 1600000 words, keeping 20007 word types

Comment: @gojomo sorry I cannot write codes in comments

Comment: Thanks, that's enough! All that text is logged at the INFO level, lower than ERROR. If you're seeing such lines, it's because you somehow ran some code – outside of Gensim! – that enabled INFO-level logging (either globally or for the module or class). Further, the formatter installed doesn't display the level, leading to this confusion. If you've got a solution, great. But I'm suggesting: watch out! It's better to simply *not enable* unwanted logging levels (digging to find where they were enabled if necessary) than to wholly turn-off logging, which risks causing more confusion later.

Comment: (For example, here's the line of Gensim source code that INFO-logs the "collecting all words and their counts" text:  https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/6e362663f23967f3c1931e2cb18d3d25f92aabb5/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L578

Answer (score 1):

Gensim's classes generally only log if you specifically turn it on, in your code, by setting either a global or module/class-specific logging level.

So, are you sure you didn't turn on more logging that you want?

Search your code for anything that sets an `INFO` or `DEBUG` level of logging - and either delete or adjust/narrow that line to either not enable, or to set a more restrictie level, on the `word2vec` module or `Word2Vec` class.